# sum instances of value in one column into different columns

Tags: sql, self-join

I have a table, session, that has an appointmentType column in it (nvarchar).  The aptType can be one of three values ( hour, halfhour, pair ).

What I need is clientname, number of hours, number of halfhours, number of pairs.

so data might look like this

```
bob | Hour
bob | Hour
bob | halfhour
bob | halfhour
bob | halfhour
bob | Pair
```

what I would like is

```
bob | 2 | 3 | 1
```

I tried variations on this theme

```
select c.firstname,
count(shour.clientid),
count(shalfhour.clientid),
count(sHour.clientid)
From Client as c 
                left  outer join [session] as sHour on c.Entityid = shour.ClientId
                left  outer join [session] as sHalfHour on c.Entityid = sHalfHour.ClientId
                left outer join [session] as sPair on c.Entityid = sPair.ClientId 
                where c.entityid =1 and  (shour.appointmentType = 'Hour' or sHalfHour.appointmentType = 'HalfHour') 
                group by c.firstname
```

the data for client 1 is that he has 35 hour apttypes and 0 for the rest.

When I do the above I get

```
bob | 1135 | 1135 | 1135
```

If I change the where to an or I get 0 rows back.

Is there anyway to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using a single join and you pivot the data using a `CASE` statement with an aggregate function:

```
select c.firstname,
    SUM(case when s.appointmentType = 'Hour' then 1 else 0 end) Hour,
    SUM(case when s.appointmentType = 'HalfHour' then 1 else 0 end) HalfHour,
    SUM(case when s.appointmentType = 'Pair' then 1 else 0 end) Pair
From Client as c 
left outer join [session] as s 
    on c.Entityid = s.ClientId
where c.entityid =1
group by c.firstname;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a44de/1)

You did not specify what RDBMS, but if you are using a database that has a `PIVOT` function (Oracle 11g+, SQL Server 2005+), then your query would look like this:

```
select firstname, Hour, HalfHour, Pair
from
(
  select c.firstname, s.appointmentType
  from Client as c 
  left outer join [session] as s 
      on c.Entityid = s.ClientId
  where c.entityid =1
) src
pivot
(
  count(appointmentType)
  for appointmentType in (Hour, HalfHour, Pair)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a44de/13)

The result of both queries is:

```
| FIRSTNAME | HOUR | HALFHOUR | PAIR |
--------------------------------------
|       Bob |    2 |        3 |    1 |
```

Comment: very nice I like it.  you had two versions a second ago and the second one was exactly like what i had with the exception of yours working and mine does not.  very frustrating.  regardless, thank you.

Comment: @Raif when I tested the join version, it wasn't working exactly right. So I removed it to include a `PIVOT` version.

Answer (score 0):

You can only count what your group is defined by, so the best way to return the counts would be as individual rows, not all in one row. In other words, this:

```
bob | Hour | 2
bob | halfhour | 3
bob | Pair | 1
```

instead of this:

```
bob | 2 | 3 | 1
```

So that query would look like:

```
SELECT 
  c.firstname,
  c.Entityid,
  count(c.clientid) as ct
FROM Client as c  
GROUP BY c.firstname, c.Entityid
```

Once you get them as individual rows, you can "pivot" that table to combine them all into one row, if you really need to. You could also do this at the application level if you have flexibility. Something along these lines should do it, not actually tested so hopefully it's close:

```
SELECT
   t.firstname,
   SUM(CASE(t.Entityid WHEN 'hour' THEN t.ct ELSE 0)) as hour,
   SUM(CASE(t.Entityid WHEN 'halfhour' THEN t.ct ELSE 0)) as halfhour,
   SUM(CASE(t.Entityid WHEN 'Pair' THEN t.ct ELSE 0)) as Pair
FROM (
    SELECT 
      c.firstname,
      c.Entityid,
      count(c.clientid) as ct
    FROM Client as c  
    GROUP BY c.firstname, c.Entityid
) t
GROUP BY t.firstname
```